# $A=S\circ O$ intuition and proof

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, intuition

I'm reading the following Lemma:

**Lemma**: Every Invertible Matrix $A$ can be represented as a composition of a symmetric Matrix $S$ and an orthogonal matrix $O$, i.e. $A=S\circ O$.

What is the intuition behind this lemma and how can I prove it?

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. I meant symmetric matrix. I'll edit.

Comment: Over the reals?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### The intuition:

Any symmetric matrix can be decomposited into $Q^{-1}DQ$ where $Q$ is orthogonal (orthonormal, actually) and $D$ is diagonal. Then, $A = Q^{-1}DQO$.

Note that the product of two orthogonal matrices is also orthogonal. An orthogonal matrix can be regarded as a linear transformation that change the orthogonal axises of a plane into another orthogonal one without stretching it.

A diagonal matrix can be seen as a linear transformation that keep the directions of all axises but stretches (none or) some of them.

So, what's the intuition of $A = Q^{-1}DQO$?

Imagine a linear operator is some kind of a transformation of a plane, you can perform the transformation directly, or you can first transform your axises into another orthogonal one without stretching them, then, stretch them, and finally, transform into another orthogonal one

### The proof

I will use the theory of *singular value decomposition*, it's an application of eigenvalue.

$A$ can be decomposited into $U\Sigma V^t$ where both $U$ and $V$ are orthogonal. To get the desired $S$, write $V^t$ as $U^tO$, or equvilently:
$$V^tU = O$$
Note that for an orthogonal, $U^tU = UU^t = I$

Then, we have $$A = U\Sigma U^t O$$

One can check that $ U\Sigma U^t$ is symmetric.

Take $S = U\Sigma U^t$, completing the proof.